# Z-index problem in IE7 with jQuery Superfish menu plugin

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index, css-sprites, superfish

I needed to modify jQuery Superfish menu plugin to accommodate using image for the menu.

There are submenus under Om oss and Medieomtale. I used sprites images for this menu.

It works fine with IE8, FF etc. However IE7 has a problem to show submenus. It shows the submenu but when I try to navigate in the submenu, it fades out.

### Editor's note

A link in this question to `www.okadadesign.no` to demonstrate the issue was removed, as it is no longer accessible.

Comment: I will try to close this question, as it was relying on a single link, and that link has died.

Answer (score 19):

I fixed the z-index problem for IE7 and IE6 by adding: position: relative; and z-index:10000; to the main #nav div that contains the  (sf-menu) and the job was done.

Answer (score 6):

I've always had to put a z-index on .sf-menu li li to get the sub-menus to show up in ie6/7.

Using [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) might help too. There are details about on the [superfish page](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

It also might be something as stupid as not specifying a "background" on .sf_menu li ul. I was using a gradient (filter in IE) and didn't specify the original background color.

```
  background: #F3F3F3; /* required for IE to retain hover state */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F3F3F3', endColorstr='#D8D8D8');
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F3F3F3), to(#D8D8D8));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #F3F3F3,  #D8D8D8);
```