# Superfish drop down menu, how to fix z-index in ie6 and ie7?

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, superfish

I am using the [`superfish`](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) plugin for `jquery` here: [clicky](http://www.kranichs.com/johncarder/)

it works fine in all modern browsers FF,Safari, Chrome, IE8

but it seems like the z-index is not working in ie6 and 7

you can see the menu is appearing, but being cut off by the elements below it.

I have tried adding a z-index everywhere I can think of but nothing seems to fix this.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have IE6 handy right now so I can test for you.

You could try adding "position:relative" to the elements you are applying z-index to.

Comment: I find that also sometimes a custom ie-only stylesheet and adding the rule "zoom: 1" to either the menu elements or the ones that it's going over combined with z-indexes solves the issue.

Comment: Maybe for extra credit you could tell me why in IE6 & 7 the drop down menus are behind the "dividers" not a huge deal but I would like to fix it if I could.

Comment: haha, thanks, I'll test in IE7 in a sec I'm not even sure where my IE6 laptop is; I did away with testing in IE6 about 6 months ago. You should check out [Stop Living In the Past](http://www.stoplivinginthepast.com/)

Comment: add position:relative;z-index:9; to the li.superfish_double_line class.

Comment: Yes that fixed it, You are awesome my friend!

Comment: feel free to +1 my comments. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) with IE you should use the bgiframe plugin. From the [superfish FAQ](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#faq):

> #### Does the Superfish plugin work with any other plugins?
>
> Yes – here are a few useful plugins
>   that you may wish to add to your menu:
>
> ...
>
> 4. **BgIframe.** Another plugin you
>   may need is Brandon Aaron’s [bgIframe
>   plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/jquery/plugins/bgiframe/docs/). This will solve the
>   Internet Explorer bug described in the
>   ‘bgIframe’ example on this site. 90%
>   of people will not need this (yes I
>   made up that statistic).

Comment: Hi thanks, I added the bgi script to my page, but it still didn't change anything. Thanks.

Comment: Well I also added this: 
#header { z-index:2; } #main_area {position:relative;z-index:1;}
Which fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I have a feeling it was my "position:relative" suggestion that fixed your problem, not the BGIframe plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Emily on this other [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069887/z-index-problem-in-ie7-with-jquery-superfish-menu-plugin/1073921#1073921) for pointing me in the right direction.

- [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) is a useful tool for checking against various IE versions
- The [superfish FAQ linked blog post](http://webdemar.com/webdesign/superfish-jquery-menu-ie-z-index-bug/) fixed the problem for IE8.
- For IE6/7 (probably combined with the fix for IE8 above), I found with my version of suckerfish that I had to put the z-index on `.sf-menu li`