# Superfish dropdown menu not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, superfish, drop-down-menu

On my site I installed superfish dropdowns, which I use on other sites as well.  Anywho, I thought all was working because they work fine in Safari, FF, and IE8.  But alas, in IE7 (and probably IE6 but I don't care!) they do not appear.

I read about Z-index issues with IE7, but none of the solutions worked.

Anyone know how to fix?  Here is the URL: http://www.recordgone.com/about-the-firm.htm

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Emily on this other [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069887/z-index-problem-in-ie7-with-jquery-superfish-menu-plugin/1073921#1073921) for pointing me in the right direction.

- [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) is a useful tool for checking against various IE versions
- The [superfish page fix](http://webdemar.com/webdesign/superfish-jquery-menu-ie-z-index-bug/) fixed the problem for IE8 - which actually comes from [this comment](http://verens.com/2005/07/15/ie-z-index-bug/#comment-309)

  > You should set the z-index on the position:relative elements (and not on the absolute elements within it if you have any).
  >
  > Also note that when setting the z-index for a positioned element, a new z-order stack will be created for the child elements.
- For IE6/7, I found with my version of suckerfish that I had to put the z-index on `.sf-menu li` rather than `.sf-menu li li`